# Receiving custom Scapy packet in a Python socket

Tags: python, linux, sockets, scapy

I am trying to send a custom packet (with a custom layer) using Scapy in python socket.

Here's the code of the client

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import socket
from scapy.all import *


TCP_PORT = 5000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.240.1', TCP_PORT))


class Reservation(Packet):
    name = "ReservationPacket"
    fields_desc=[ ByteField("id", 0),
         BitField("type",None, 0),
         X3BytesField("update", 0),
         ByteField("rssiap", 0)]

k = IP(dst="192.168.240.1")/Reservation()
k.show()
send(k)

print "Reservation Message Sent"

s.close()
```

and the packet k appears to be successfully created and sent.

Here's the server which is responsible to receive the packet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
from scapy.all import *


class Reservation(Packet):
    name = "ReservationPacket"
    fields_desc=[ ByteField("id", 0),
        BitField("type",None, 0),
        X3BytesField("update", 0),
        ByteField("rssiap", 0)]


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('192.168.240.1', 5000))
s.listen(1)

while True :

    conn, addr = s.accept()

    print 'Connection address:', addr

    print ''

    data = conn.recv(1024)
    data.show()
    conn.close

s.close()
```

and this is the output I get from the server:

```
Connection address: ('192.168.240.5', 58454)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "server.py", line 36, in <module>
  data.show()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'show'
```

How can I receive my packet and decode it to read its custom layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data became a string in this line:

```
data = conn.recv(1024)
```

Checking the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

> socket.recv(bufsize[, flags]) Receive data from the socket. The
>   return value is a string representing the data received. The maximum
>   amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize. See the
>   Unix manual page recv(2) for the meaning of the optional argument
>   flags; it defaults to zero.

What are you trying to do with data.show(), you just could print the data with:

```
print data
```

Also follow this link to decode the string: 
[Python - converting sock.recv to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979764/python-converting-sock-recv-to-string)

```
stringdata = data.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: data.show() should show the fields of my packet. If I try "print data" I don't get anything.
I would like also to access the fields of my packet, like data.type but it's not working:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 36, in <module>
    print data.id
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: You didnt read the documentation I pasted there. This data is a string, it hasnt id or show attributes, if you print it and its None it means it's empty.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't know how to do, how can I receive it and then use the packet fields?